# Optimal way for "Lookup" type operations between multiple dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

A common task I seem to have is something like this:

DataFrame A contains among its columns an "id" with some kind of "price" and "description". This would typically be a very large dataset.

And there are 2 much smaller DataFrames: one containing columns where the (few) "descriptions" are linked to a "type" and another small DataFrame links the types to a price modifier.

The operations would be to modify the price column in DataFrame A, using a "Lookup", to find its "type" via the description and in turn find the price modifier

For example,

id, desc, price
12345, sausage, £3
...

id, desc, type
sausage, meat

type, modifier
meat, -0.5

My clumsy way of doing this has been as follows:

Joining in the extra tables via some common key, which has just been lucky (that they shared a common key)

```py
dfA = dfA.join(dfB.set_index('key'), on='key')
```

but that just ends up with the "Lookup" values from a small table being copied into every row of the original DataFrame A, which to me just seems like a clumsy bozo way to do it.

The advantage is that it is now easier to do column-wise logic in the newly updated DataFrame A.

The kind of functionality I would like (but do not know how to word well enough to google is this:)

For the entire DataFrame A, use the value in some column (let's assume the value to be "a") to "lookup" in DataFrame B, to find "a" in some column (which might or might not have the same name as A, but the values will be there), and in turn this value "b" could be referenced into DataFrame C to get some other value etc.

In muppet logic, with 1 lookup level:

```
dfA['new_value'] = df['old_value'] + (use value in dfA'type' column to look into dfB column 'bcol' to get the value in dfB'offset')
```

and then a 2 lookup level would instead use the value in the dfB 'offset' column to look at dfC column 'modifier' etc.

Is this kind of logic or operation known as something that I can google around a bit, it feels like I often have to do this kind of thing, using smaller tables of modifiers to reference directly or in several chained steps to adjust something in the much bigger main data table

(an example would be great but right now I am hitting that frustration wall of not really having a good intuition for this kind of logic since the power of dataframes is all these kind of "behind the curtain" operations using syntax that looks like its addressing only a single cell!, I always think in terms of old style basic type loops and stuff.

I finally found a nice explanation of lambda functions where I can understand the "x" being "the thing in this cell" but I am still learning!)

sorry this became a bit long and rambling, if you can suggest a better title I am happy to edit this in retrospect if it will be useful to others in future

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have the following DataFrames:

**DataFrame A (df_A)**

| id | desc | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | sausage | 3 |
| 2 | cheese | 1.5 |
| 3 | eggs | 5 |
| 4 | milk | 2.5 |

**DataFrame B (df_B)**

| id | desc | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | sausage | meat |
| 2 | eggs | poulty |
| 3 | cheese | dairy |
| 4 | milk | dairy |

**DataFrame C (df_C)**

| id | type | modifier |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | meat | -0.5 |
| 2 | poultry | 0.75 |
| 3 | dairy | -1 |

To get the new price of all items in DataFrame A, you can do something like

```py
def get_modified_price(row):
    # Gets the item description
    desc = row['desc']

    # Gets the item type
    type = df_B[df_B['desc'] == desc]['type']

    # Gets the item modifier
    modifier = df_C[df_C['type'] == type]['modifier']

    # Returns the modified price
    return row['price'] + modifier

df_A['modified_price'] = df.apply(get_modified_price)
```

To learn more about these kinds of operations, you can look into row-wise operations and pandas functions such as [pd.map](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) and [pd.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html).

Also, since you mentioned lambda functions in your question, you can also write the code above as

```py
df_A['modified_price'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['price'] + df_C[df_C['type'] == df_B[df_B['desc'] == row['desc']]['type']]['modifier'])
```

Comment: this is awesome, thanks, I have completely missed this "row" usage as well, thats super useful thanks